# Create a data frame containin all possible permutations/combination given a string specifying the number of repetitions

Tags: python, string, loops, combinations, permutation

I would like to create a data frame that contains by row the 24^ combinations for all the letters of the alphabet, i.e. starting with:

```
begin = pd.DataFrame({
"combi":["AAA","AAB","AAC","AAD"]})
```

and ending with:

```
end = pd.DataFrame({
"combi":["ZZW","ZZX","ZZY","ZZZ"]})
```

this is what if found out:

```py
names = list(itertools.combinations(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], 3))
#names['concat'] = pd.Series(names.fillna('').values.tolist()).str.join('')
print(names)
```

Contentwise it is fine but I need it in the shape as above.

Comment: why do you expect `"combi":["AA","AB","AC","AD"]})` if you are pass 3 as an argument to combinations. that will produce `"combi":["AAA","AAB","AAC","AAD"]})`

Comment: Did you mean 26^3 (assuming you meant the English alphabet)? Why don't you simply cast the result of what you have to a DataFrame with `DataFrame(names)`?

Comment: @JamiuS. yes, you are right: "AAA" and so on. Sorry for the mistake, I started with 2. Sorry.

Comment: @Grismar you are right... accordingly to the English alphabet 26. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible approach using [`product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from itertools:

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

combi = list(product(list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), repeat=3))
df = pd.DataFrame({'combi': [''.join(alpha) for alpha in combi]})
print(df)
```

You could also get the alphabets using [`string.ascii_uppercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase) by importing `string` instead of having to write them.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product
import string

alphabets = string.ascii_uppercase
alpha_combi = [''.join(alpha) for alpha in product(alphabets, repeat=3)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'combi': alpha_combi})
print(df)
```

---

```
      combi
0       AAA
1       AAB
2       AAC
3       AAD
4       AAE
...     ...
17571   ZZV
17572   ZZW
17573   ZZX
17574   ZZY
17575   ZZZ
```